# How do I get the name or a list of names from an ADM2 object at run time?

Tags: progress-4gl, adm2

I have a smart window which contain some smart object.I want to know the name of all the object at run time or list of all the object at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the InstanceNames property of the container, either using

```
{get InstanceNames hdlContainer cInstanceNames}
```

or

```
cInstanceNames = dynamic-function('getInstanceNames' in hdlContainer)
```

Where cInstanceNames is a comma-delimited string.

If you want to be able to recurse into the container's containers (and container's containers' containers) use the ContainerTargets property instead, which returns a list of handles, and then apply the above to each container target.